Understanding 同じ楓の樹でも同じ色を枝に着けているものは一つもなかった
From Kokoro chapter 26:

私は私を包む若葉の色に心を奪われていた。その若葉の色をよくよく眺めると、一々違っていた。同じ楓の樹でも同じ色を枝に着けているものは一つもなかった。

I found the last sentence bit ambiguous. I am not quite sure about the meaning of 同じ楓の樹でも and what もの might refer to. もの can either refer to a maple tree or a leaf of a maple tree. The possible interpretations are

Even if they are all maple trees, no two trees share the same color.

Even if they are all maple trees, no two leaves from any of these trees share the same color.

Even if it is the same tree, no two leaves from that tree share the same color.


I'd put money that 2 is correct.

Though I suspect this is a result of unfamiliarity with English usage, rather than of any flaw in your understanding of the Japanese, in each of these cases "even if" isn't quite right. Since it is clear that all the trees are in fact maples, we would say "even though" or "although." (Great that you're reading Kokoro, by the way, and I've been profiting from the answers to the excellent questions you're posting as you make your way through it!)


A: その若葉の色をよくよく眺めると、一々違っていた。
B: 同じ楓の樹でも同じ色を枝に着けているものは一つもなかった。

Looking at these sentences separately and straightforwardly, Sentence A means that each individual leaf has a different color. However, Sentence B means the color differs from tree to tree (もの refers to maple trees). When these two sentences are combined, it's not impossible to interpret that the colors of thousands of leaves across all trees are all different from each other.
In reality, it is difficult for humans to distinguish thousands of colors. While the degree of 紅葉 varies from tree to tree, the color of maple leaves on a single tree is relatively uniform. You can confirm this by seeing the photos in this guide. Therefore, although Sentence A appears a little exaggerated and potentially confusing, I think Sentence B by itself can be straightforwardly interpreted as meaning 1 in your list.

I partly agree with naruto's answer. もの refers to a maple tree, and not its leaf. This is because if もの referred to a leaf, 枝に would not make sense (since branch is not a part of a leaf). However, the interpretation of the whole sentence seems ambiguous even for native speakers. (I have never read Kokoro, so it can be mine that is off context.)
My interpretation is close to your second one.
If taking the sentence literally, 同じ色を枝に着ける is talking about the color of branches, which seems off topic for me, not impossible though. So, in my opinion, 同じ色 does not simply mean “the same color” but plays a role of “a leaf in the same color” (mere omission or metonymy?) and thus the sentence not based on 色をつける but on 葉をつける.
As a result, my interpretation is as follows: “Even though they are all same “maple” trees, none of them has (leaves of) the same color on its branches.”
